# Aplicativo android fecha assim que carrega (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, android

Eu instalei o Android SDK tudo certinho, instalei os drivers USB do meu Motorola Moto G. Tá tudo certo, tanto que quando vou executar a aplicação diretamente do Eclipse, ele acha o meu dispositivo conectado. Depuração USB está habilitada.

Só que quando rodo a aplicação, e o Eclipse faz a instalação do .apk, o meu aparelho, ao abrir a aplicação, exibe instantaneamente "O My App parou".

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo fazer rodar. Quero rodar no meu aparelho por que é Android KitKat e porque o AVD é meio lento, às vezes.

O logcat exibe isso quando executo a aplicação no dispositivo:

```
04-28 22:27:07.680: W/dalvikvm(13905): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1630 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
04-28 22:27:07.681: D/dalvikvm(13905): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
04-28 22:27:07.682: D/AndroidRuntime(13905): Shutting down VM
04-28 22:27:07.682: W/dalvikvm(13905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ef5d40)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 13905
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:104)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-28 22:27:07.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: E no emulador funciona bem?

Comment: Também não, @JorgeB.

Comment: Pelo que vi no stacktrace, ele precisa de um jar que está referenciado no BuildPath: appcompat_v7.jar. Só que ele tá referenciando esse cara e não tá achando.

Comment: Resolvi o problema @JorgeB. Eu adicionei no AndroidManifest.xml a seguinte linha: `<library android:name="C:\dev\android\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar" />`

Comment: Cria uma resposta com o que fizeste e daqui a dois dias podes aceita-la.

Comment: Já criei. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido o problema.

Adicionei no AndroidManifest.xml a linha

```
<library android:name="C:\dev\android\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar" />
```

O aplicativo rodou com sucesso. :)

Comment: Uma referência no [SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992434/unable-to-run-androids-hello-world-in-ecplise)